# searching venues by name only

Tags: foursquare

i'm building a small application for searching on venues by it's name

i'm using the Foursquare API v2  . the venue search interface
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search

the problem is you have to state  the **LL**  property or the **near** property

so queires that work now is search for macdonald's near chigaco

but what if i want to search for all venues with that keyword , without satisfying a place near it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You currently need to pass a location (ll or near) for venues/search -- foursquare does not support searching for venues without a geographical scope.

There is a highly experimental "global" intent for venues search, but it's not supported in any way.

Comment: so are there a best practice or something to grab all the venues , like the case of categories ?

Comment: To get back venues of a certain category, specify the categoryId param of /venues/search. There is no way to download all venues and the terms do not allow scraping of the API.